# how to render mathml using ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: c#, html, .net, angularjs

I have equations in mathml format stored in sqlserver. Using linq i'm passing equations in list to UI. In UI i have tried to render those mathml string using `ng-repeat` but it won't work at all.

[when i am directly putting the mathml string inside any div its rendering equations correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Klt.jpg)

[In ng-repeat it showing the mathml format as it is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSko4.jpg)

Mathml string is

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mroot>
        <mn>4</mn>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </mroot>
    <mo>+</mo>
    <mfrac>
        <mn>5</mn>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </mfrac>
    <mo>&#xA0;</mo>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mo>&#xA0;</mo>
    <mfenced open="[" close="]">
        <mtable>
            <mtr>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </mtd>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </mtd>
            </mtr>
            <mtr>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>8</mn>
                </mtd>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>4</mn>
                </mtd>
            </mtr>
        </mtable>
    </mfenced>
</math>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good idea use this directive: 
[ngMathJax](https://github.com/yonibaciu/ngMathJax)

An example of how it'd work:

```html
<div ng-math-jax>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mroot>
        <mn>4</mn>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </mroot>
    <mo>+</mo>
    <mfrac>
        <mn>5</mn>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </mfrac>
    <mo>&#xA0;</mo>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mo>&#xA0;</mo>
    <mfenced open="[" close="]">
        <mtable>
            <mtr>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </mtd>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </mtd>
            </mtr>
            <mtr>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>8</mn>
                </mtd>
                <mtd>
                    <mn>4</mn>
                </mtd>
            </mtr>
        </mtable>
    </mfenced>
</math>
</div>
```